# Explain the use of below function with meaning in iphone

Tags: iphone

I m confused to use following methods and i want the clear meaning of all so that i can use that perfectly in my project

1. `-(void)viewWillAppear`
2. `-(void)viewWillDisappear`
3. -`(void)viewDidLoad`
4. `-(void)viewDidUnload`
5. `-(void)viewDidAppear`
6. `-(void)viewDidDisappear`

Please can any body who knows these very well then please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the iPhone Developer Documentation for [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)? It explains it well I think.

Answer (score 3):

This is from the top of my head. Here is some more info: [Custom View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html)

**-(void)viewWillAppear**
Fired just before the uiview appears on the screen.

**-(void)viewWillDisappear**
Fired just before the uiview disappears from the screen.

**-(void)viewDidLoad**
Fired after the uview loaded into memory and after the IBOutlets are hooked up (if any)

**-(void)viewDidUnload**
Fired after the uview unloaded from memory.

**-(void)viewDidAppear**
Fired after the view appeared on the screen.

**-(void)viewDidDisappear**
Fired after view disappeared from the screen.